# Smoothly animated fractal tree using p5.js

Tags: javascript, animation, smoothing, p5.js, fractals

I'm trying to make a smoothly animated fractal tree using p5.js. I have completely no idea how to make branches generate one by one, instead of generating  all at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
function draw() {
    background(51);
    strokeWeight(5);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    translate(600, height);

    drawLine(300);
}

function drawLine(length) {
    miliseconds = millis() / 10;
    if(miliseconds < length) {
        line(0, 0, 0, -miliseconds);
    }
    else {
        line(0, 0, 0, -length);
    }

    translate(0, -length);

    if(length > 50) {
        push();
        rotate(PI / 4);
        drawLine(length * 0.67);
        pop();
        push();
        rotate(-(PI / 4));
        drawLine(length * 0.67);
        pop();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is pretty broad. Stack Overflow isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense:

One way you might do this is by keeping track of how many branches have been drawn for each frame, and only continuing to draw until you reach that limit. You might do this with a sketch-level variable you reset every frame, or you might pass it in as an argument to the `drawLine()` function.

Here's a very very basic idea of what I'm talking about:

```
int currentLimit = 1;

void draw(){
   exampleRecursiveFunction(0, currentLimit);
   currentLimit++;
}

void exampleRecursiveFunction(int count, int limit){
   drawMe();
   if(count < limit){
      exampleRecursiveFunction(count+1, limit);
   }
}
```